# Mistake in exercise 1-6 on p. 4 of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functions, inner-products

The question states:

"Let $f$ and $g$ be integrable on $[a, b]$.

a) Prove that $|\int_a^b{fg}|\leq{\sqrt{\int_a^b{f^2}}}\sqrt{\int_a^b{g^2}}$. *Hint:* Consider separately the cases $0=\int_a^b(f-\lambda{g})^2$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0<\int_a^b(f-\lambda{g})^2$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

b) If equality holds, must $f=\lambda{g}$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$? What if $f$ and $g$ are continuous?

c) Show that Theorem 1-1(2) [the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality] is a special case of (a)."

My question is about part (b). Can't we just let $g=0$ and let $f$ always be positive in both cases so that equality holds but there is no $\lambda$ such that $f=\lambda{g}$? Did Spivak mean to require that $f$ and $g$ be non-zero? If they are both non-zero and not necessarily continuous though, we can just let $g=0$ everywhere except on a set of measure $0$, so equality holds but $f$ need not equal $\lambda{g}$ for some $\lambda$. If $g$ is continuous, it can't be $0$ everywhere except on a set of measure $0$ and still have $\int_a^bg^2=0$. We can still let $g=\frac{1}{\lambda}f$ on only part of the interval though (say $[a, (a+b)/2]$) and $0$ everywhere else, in which case we still have equality, but on $[(a+b)/2, b]$ $\ \ f$ need not equal $\lambda{g}$ for some $\lambda$. Did Spivak maybe mean for $f$ and $g$ to be non-zero everywhere, or everywhere except a set of measure $0$?

Does anyone know what the original intent for part (b) of this exercise and its solution was?

Comment: There is no error in the question: the question is a yes or no question, not a proof question. That is, you have the question right, and the answer in both cases is "no".

A more interesting, and difficult, version of this problem would involve replacing $f = \lambda g$ with $af + bg = 0$, for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The way the question was asked though it seemed like the expected answer would "no" and "yes" in the continuous case. If we replace the condition like you say, the answer is still "no" and "no" (using $f>0$ and $g=0$), unless you allow $a, b=0$ . . .

Comment: And I see that you're probably saying we can let $a$ or $b$ $=0$ but not both, i.e., that $f$ and $g$ are linearly dependent. Seems like in this case the answer is indeed "yes" if continuity is required and "no" otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I did indeed mean linearly dependent.